# Implementing EINVAL, EPERM, ESRCH in Kill()

Tags: c, unix, ubuntu, posix

I am trying to implement EINVAL, EPERM, ESRCH in my program.

> ERRORS
>  EINVAL An invalid signal
>   was specified.
>  EPERM  The process
>   does not have permission to send the
>   signal to any of the target processes.
>   ESRCH  The  pid or process group does
>   not exist.

Here's my source code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{

 int errno, pid;

 puts("Enter a process id : ");
 scanf("%d", &pid);

    errno = kill(pid, 1);

 if(errno == -1)
 {
  printf("Cannot find or kill the specified process\n");

 }


 switch(errno)
 {
  case EINVAL:
   printf("An invalid signal was specified.\n");
   break;

  case EPERM:
   printf("The process does not have permission to send the signal to any of the target processes.\n");
   break;

  case ESRCH:
   printf("The  pid or process group does not exist.");
   break;
 }

}
```

And when I compile the program I get the following errors.

> unipro@ubuguest:/SoftDev/ADSD/Module
>   1/Unit 1/Pratice/C/C_adv/unix$ cc
>   killApp.c -o killApp
>  killApp.c: In
>   function ‘main’:
>  killApp.c:29:
>   error: ‘EINVAL’ undeclared (first use
>   in this function)
>  killApp.c:29:
>   error: (Each undeclared identifier is
>   reported only once
>  killApp.c:29:
>   error: for each function it appears
>   in.)
>  killApp.c:33: error: ‘EPERM’
>   undeclared (first use in this
>   function)
>  killApp.c:37: error:
>   ‘ESRCH’ undeclared (first use in this
>   function)
>   unipro@ubuguest:/SoftDev/ADSD/Module
>   1/Unit 1/Pratice/C/C_adv/unix$

So where are EINVAL, EPERM, ESRCH defined? Do I need to define any additional header file? Or I am implementing it in a wrong way?

**Updated Code [working code] :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{

    int status, pid;

    puts("Enter a process id : ");
    scanf("%d", &pid);

    status = kill(pid, 1);



    switch(errno)
    {
        case EINVAL:
            printf("An invalid signal was specified.\n");
            break;

        case EPERM:
            printf("The process does not have permission to send the signal to any of the target processes.\n");
            break;

        case ESRCH:
            printf("The  pid or process group does not exist.");
            break;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You probably should be using `strerror` or `perror` to get the error messages rather than writing your own. It's easier, more concise, and on many systems it will get you translations to the user's native language at no cost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work, first you should `#include <errno.h>` (as that's where `errno` is defined, as are the error codes).
Second, don't call your local return value variable errno (as that exists and is where the error code will be).

eg.

```
#include <errno.h>
/* ... */

int rc;
/* ... */

rc = kill(pid, SIGHUP);
if (rc != 0)
{
    switch (errno) {...}
}
```

Comment: what is SIGHUP? is it a signal?

Comment: `SIGHUP` is a signal (the same as the `1` in your code), for more information about errno see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno